# JavaScript and Document.Writeln() method

Tags: javascript, html

I am a newcomer on JavaScript and now I'm doing some practices by myself. One of the practices is to get the value from a textbox and then write it down on an Alert window, or on a HTML page using `Document.writeln()`. But then, I notice some strange problem. When I try to run this javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>HTML Practice</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            function testing(){

                window.alert("testing");
                document.writeln("test");
                document.writeln("test");
                document.writeln("test");
                document.writeln("test");
                window.alert(document.getElementById('test0').value);
                window.alert(document.getElementById('test2').value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>TextBox</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="test0" value="12" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Another TextBox</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="test2" value="3" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" id="button" value="Click here!" onclick="testing()" /></td>
                <td>Click this button to read the text in textbox</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The alert window appear, but the last two alert window doesn't appear.
Strangely, when I move two bottom line on javascript to the top like this

```
window.alert(document.getElementById('test0').value); //this code is now on top
window.alert(document.getElementById('test2').value);    
window.alert("testing");
document.writeln("test");
document.writeln("test");
document.writeln("test");
document.writeln("test");
```

Those two alert window appear. There is also another problem. I try some variation to track this problem:

```
document.writeln(document.getElementById('test0').value);
document.writeln(document.getElementById('test2').value);    
window.alert("testing");
document.writeln("test");
document.writeln("test");
document.writeln("test");
document.writeln("test");
```

`test0` and `test2` are IDs of my two textbox. when the value of `test0` and `test2` are 12 and 3, respectively, no alert window appear and this is what appears on the HTML page:

```
12
```

But when I put those two top line on the bottom like this:

```
window.alert("testing");
document.writeln("test");
document.writeln("test");
document.writeln("test");
document.writeln("test");
document.writeln(document.getElementById('test0').value);
document.writeln(document.getElementById('test2').value); //Now on the bottom
```

Using same textbox value above, the alert window appears and this is what appears on the HTML page

```
test test test test
```

What I expected is the output should be like this:

```
test
test
test
test
12
3
```

Now I'm curious, why when I only change the position of the line, the output is very different? Is there something wrong on my usage of `Document.Writeln()`?

Comment: Have tried running it in a JavaScript debugger/console? Chrome has one built-in, Firefox has to exquisite `Firebug` plugin.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: I already using Firebug to trackdown the problem. One thing that I notice when tracking the code is after document.writeln() line, the code breaks. That's why I think the problem lies on that method

@ArunKillu
The last example is still using 12 and 3 as the value of 'test0' and 'test2' textboxes respectively.

Comment: As you are a beginner in javascript I can strongly recommend this http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you write in your document with

```
document.writeline("test");
```

you **remove** all the exisiting HTML, **including** the `<input>` boxes. If they do not exist, `document.getelementById("test0");` will return `null`.

Easy to find out by using Firebug, just write `document.writeln("test")` in the console, you'll see all your elements are gone.

Answer (score 0):

The very first line of js function testing

```
document.writeln(document.getElementById('test2').value);
```

writes the value of input field test2 ie-12 and clears the all other html elements, 
therefore `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` will be raised when you try to access a property of an element that does not exist in dom.

Answer (score 0):

document.writeln() is a waste of time, as it will not do what the programmer usually intends for it to do.  Just use write() to render 
 tags.